# how to change django user to my existing user table in database and generate tokens

Tags: python, django, model, jwt

Hello guys I have a problem here, I want to change my django user to this user which is existed in database with it's own fields and generate token access for each one of the the code is right below

class Persons(models.Model):
personid = models.AutoField(db_column='PersonID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personcode = models.CharField(db_column='PersonCode', unique=True, max_length=50, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS')  # Field name made lowercase.
personimage = models.BinaryField(db_column='PersonImage', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personname = models.CharField(db_column='PersonName', max_length=200, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS')  # Field name made lowercase.
personpost = models.CharField(db_column='PersonPost', max_length=50, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personstype = models.DecimalField(db_column='PersonsType', max_digits=1, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
employeepassword = models.CharField(db_column='EmployeePassword', max_length=50, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personphone = models.CharField(db_column='PersonPhone', max_length=50, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personmobile = models.CharField(db_column='PersonMobile', max_length=50, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personmail = models.CharField(db_column='PersonMail', max_length=200, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personaddress = models.CharField(db_column='PersonAddress', max_length=500, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personbirthcertificateid = models.CharField(db_column='PersonBirthCertificateID', max_length=50, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personplaceofissue = models.CharField(db_column='PersonPlaceOfIssue', max_length=200, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personfathername = models.CharField(db_column='PersonFatherName', max_length=200, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
education = models.CharField(db_column='Education', max_length=200, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personbirthdate = models.CharField(db_column='PersonBirthDate', max_length=11, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personweddate = models.CharField(db_column='PersonWedDate', max_length=11, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personfavoritedate = models.CharField(db_column='PersonFavoriteDate', max_length=11, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personcomment = models.CharField(db_column='PersonComment', max_length=500, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
entrancedate = models.CharField(db_column='EntranceDate', max_length=11, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personreagentid = models.ForeignKey('self', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='PersonReagentId', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
personregisterdate = models.CharField(db_column='PersonRegisterDate', max_length=11, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
activeinclub = models.BooleanField(db_column='ActiveInClub')  # Field name made lowercase.
USERNAME_FIELD='personcode'
class Meta:
managed = False
db_table = 'Persons'

I can't make it my main user I want to use JWT tokens but JWT only works with auth.user of django and I want to declear the mentioned model as my main user so I can use JWT Tokens

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.